# WordPress sending 404 when hooking into send_headers

Tags: php, wordpress, http-status-code-404

I'm trying to hook into the `send_headers` function of WordPress so I can check to see if a `sitemap.xml` was requested. That way, I can serve up a custom PHP function to automatically generate the XML based on WordPress posts and pages.

```
add_action( 'send_headers', 'custom_send_headers');
if( !function_exists('custom_send_headers') ) :
    function custom_send_headers( )
    {
        global $route, $wp_query, $window_title;
        $bits = explode( "/", $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] );

        if( $bits[1] === 'sitemap.xml' )
        {
            if ( $wp_query->is_404 ) {
                $wp_query->is_404 = false;
            }
            include('sitemap.php');
            die();
        }
    }
endif;
```

Everything is serving up properly, and my PHP file is including the appropriate headers:

```
<?php header('Content-Type: application/xml'); ?>
<?php echo '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>'; ?>
<urlset xmlns="http://www.sitemaps.org/schemas/sitemap/0.9">
    ....
</urlset>
```

Why would WordPress be sending 404?

I tried using WordPress templates and that didn't seem to work.

```
$template = locate_template('sitemap.php');
load_template($template);
```

Is there another function I should be hooking into? Did I miss something else that I should be doing?

Comment: Have you registered a rewrite rule for `sitemap.xml`?

Comment: Are you suggesting I manually modify my .htaccess file? I was trying to avoid that, hence the hooking into WordPress's headers.

Comment: You may still need to send a `200 OK` header since you're circumventing the normal approach to sending content. can you try a `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");` before your `include`?

Comment: That worked. Thanks. If you want to submit an answer, I'll accept whenever possible. Appreciate the quick response!

Comment: Thanks. I also asked about the re-write rule to see if the code you've written was in the context of a file not found. you can probably ditch the `$wp_query->is_404 = false;` stuff too or include the 200 OK header in it's place :)

Comment: Yeah, just for future reference, I did end up removing those lines and it worked as designed. Cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may still need to send a `200 OK` header since you're circumventing the normal approach to sending content.

Add `header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");` before your `include('sitemap.php');`